# Using jQueryExtern with Haxe Synax Error

Tags: jquery, haxe, each

I have just started to use Haxe and imported the jQueryExtern,
when I'm trying to use

```
        new JQuery(".roles:checked").each(function(){

        });
```

I'm getting a Compiler error:

```
src/LeftList.hx:69: lines 69-71 : Void -> Void should be Int -> js.html.Node -> Void
src/LeftList.hx:69: lines 69-71 : For function argument '_function'
```

Can't figure out why,

Help will be much appreciated,

Nevo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryExtern project provides the [following function definition](https://github.com/andyli/jQueryExternForHaxe/blob/master/jQuery/JQuery.hx#L830):

```
public function each(_function:Int -> js.html.Node -> Void):jQuery.JQuery;
```

The thing to notice is that the function argument specifies that both "Int" and "Node" arguments must exist on the function - they are not optional.  (If you think this is incorrect, maybe file an issue on the Github page for [jQueryExternForHaxe](https://github.com/andyli/jQueryExternForHaxe/)?)  Because Haxe is strictly typed, it will only accept a function that exactly matches the type signature used in the definition.

The following code should work:

```
    new JQuery(".roles:checked").each(function(index,node){
      $type(index); // Int
      $type(node); // js.html.Node
    });
```